# Basic neural network, weights too high

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, neural-network

I am trying to code a very basic neural network in python, with 3 input nodes with a value of 0 or 1 and a single output node, with a value of 0 or 1. The output should be almost equal to the second input, but after training, the weights are way way too high, and the network almost always guesses 1.

I am using python 3.7 with numpy and scipy. I have tried changing the training set, the new instance, and the random seed

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import expit as ex

rand.seed(10)
training_set=[[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]] #The training sets and their outputs
training_outputs=[0,1,0,1]
weightlst=[rand.uniform(-1,1),rand.uniform(-1,1),rand.uniform(-1,1)]  #Weights are randomly set with a value between -1 and 1

print('Random weights\n'+str(weightlst))

def calcout(inputs,weights):    #Calculate the expected output with given inputs and weights
    output=0.5

    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        output=output+(inputs[i]*weights[i])
    #print('\nmy output is ' + str(ex(output)))
    return ex(output)                 #Return the output on a sigmoid curve between 0 and 1

def adj(expected_output,training_output,weights,inputs):   #Adjust the weights based on the expected output, true (training) output and the weights
    adjweights=[]
    error=expected_output-training_output

    for i in weights:
        adjweights.append(i+(error*(expected_output*(1-expected_output))))
    return adjweights

                                                       #Train the network, adjusting weights each time
training_iterations=10000
for k in range(training_iterations):
    for l in range(len(training_set)):

        expected=calcout(training_set[l],weightlst)
        weightlst=adj(expected,training_outputs[l],weightlst,training_set[l])

new_instance=[1,0,0]           #Calculate and return the expected output of a new instance

print('Adjusted weights\n'+str(weightlst))
print('\nExpected output of new instance = ' + str(calcout(new_instance,weightlst)))
```

The expected output would be 0, or something very close to it, but no matter what i set new_instance to, the output is still

```
Random weights
[-0.7312715117751976, 0.6948674738744653, 0.5275492379532281]
Adjusted weights
[1999.6135460307303, 2001.03968501638, 2000.8723667804588]

Expected output of new instance = 1.0
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: what is your function `adj` expected to do ? Also why are you initializing output to 0.5 ?

Comment: hey mujjiga, my `adj` function adjusts the weights by the error (difference between true output and expected output) divided by the confidence. The 0.5 initialization is to bias the output

Comment: This is a very different method to adjust weights, can you point to some resources to understand this weight updates better.

Comment: it is actually a standard method (https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/), just written in a roundabout way (thanks for pointing that out), i have editd the code to be a bit more readable and to make more sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bugs**:

- No bias used in the neuron
- error=training_output-expected_output (not the other way around) for gradient decent
- weight update rule of ith weight `w_i = w_i + learning_rate * delta_w_i`,  (delta_w_i is gradient of loss with respect to w_i)
- For squared loss `delta_w_i = error*sample[i]` (ith value of input vector sample)
- Since you have only one neuron (one hidden layer or size 1) your model can only learn linearly separable data (it is only a linear classifier). Examples of linearly separable data are data generated by functions like boolean `AND`, `OR`. Note that boolean `XOR` is not linearly separable.

### Code with bugs fixed

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import expit as ex

rand.seed(10)
training_set=[[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]] #The training sets and their outputs
training_outputs=[1,1,0,1] # Boolean OR of input vector
#training_outputs=[0,0,,1] # Boolean AND of input vector

weightlst=[rand.uniform(-1,1),rand.uniform(-1,1),rand.uniform(-1,1)]  #Weights are randomly set with a value between -1 and 1
bias = rand.uniform(-1,1)

print('Random weights\n'+str(weightlst))

def calcout(inputs,weights, bias):    #Calculate the expected output with given inputs and weights
    output=bias
    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        output=output+(inputs[i]*weights[i])
    #print('\nmy output is ' + str(ex(output)))
    return ex(output)                 #Return the output on a sigmoid curve between 0 and 1

def adj(expected_output,training_output,weights,bias,inputs):   #Adjust the weights based on the expected output, true (training) output and the weights
    adjweights=[]
    error=training_output-expected_output
    lr = 0.1
    for j, i in enumerate(weights):
        adjweights.append(i+error*inputs[j]*lr)
    adjbias = bias+error*lr
    return adjweights, adjbias

#Train the network, adjusting weights each time
training_iterations=10000
for k in range(training_iterations):
    for l in range(len(training_set)):
        expected=calcout(training_set[l],weightlst, bias)
        weightlst, bias =adj(expected,training_outputs[l],weightlst,bias,training_set[l])

new_instance=[1,0,0]           #Calculate and return the expected output of a new instance

print('Adjusted weights\n'+str(weightlst))
print('\nExpected output of new instance = ' + str(calcout(new_instance,weightlst, bias)))
```

**Output:**

```
Random weights
[0.142805189379827, -0.14222189064977075, 0.15618260226894076]
Adjusted weights
[6.196759842119063, 11.71208191137411, 6.210137255008176]
Expected output of new instance = 0.6655563851223694
```

As up can see for input `[1,0,0]` the model predicted the probability `0.66` which is class 1 (since 0.66>0.5). It is correct as the output class is OR of input vector.

### Note:

For learning/understanding how each weight is updated it is ok to code like above, but in practice all the operations are vectorised. Check the [link](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2015_singlelayer_neurons.html) for vectorized implementation.

Comment: Thanks @mujjiga, this straightforward solution is exactly what I was looking for